# FuelPHP routes.php not working

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url-routing, fuelphp

I have a very basic setup with a new Fuel checkout.

`fuel/app/classes/controllers/auth.php`

```
class Controller_Auth extends Controller
{
    public function action_login()
    {
        return View::forge('auth/login');
    }
}
```

`fuel/app/views/auth/login.php`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>FuelPHP Framework</title>
    <?php echo Asset::css('bootstrap.css'); ?>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <style>
        #login-block {
            margin: auto;
            border: 1px solid #ddd;
            -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
            -moz-border-radius: 4px;
            border-radius: 4px;
            -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.055);
            -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.055);
            box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.055);
            padding: 5px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="content" class="container-fluid">
        <div id="login-block">
            <h1>Login</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php echo Asset::js('jquery.min.js'); ?>
    <?php echo Asset::js('bootstrap.js'); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

`fuel/app/config/routes.php`

```
return array(
    '_root_'        => 'settings/index',  // The default route
    '_404_'         => '404',    // The main 404 route
    'login'         => 'auth/login',
);
```

However, visiting `http://localhost/tmp/public/login` gives a 404. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you run Apache, your problem may reside on a misconfigured **.htaccess** file.

From the URL you're trying to access, a configuration like the following should suffice:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

The **.htaccess** I'm reffering to is the one on the same directory as the **index.php**, and normaly defaults to: **/fuel/public/.htaccess**

If the above doesn't work, you may see a notice on the **[file](https://github.com/fuel/fuel/blob/1.6/develop/public/.htaccess)** that says:

**# NOTICE: If you get a 404 play with combinations of the following commented out lines**

Try to fiddle with it, until you get it right.

Comment: Thanks, I'm fiddling with it as we speak.

Comment: You should also test the different URLs to see which ones work. Try opening:
- http://localhost/tmp/public/index.php/auth/login
- http://localhost/tmp/public/auth/login
- http://localhost/tmp/public/login

Also check the apache access.log to see the file paths that are being called and see if they make sense.

Comment: `/public/index.php/login` and `/public/index.php/auth/login` both work -- while any other combination doesn't. Can't seem to get it to work by modifying the htaccess file.

Comment: I fixed it, thanks for setting me on the right track. Turns out I had disabled overrides in the apache settings.